# C# Structure with inner Clear() method

Tags: c#, methods, structure, internals

I want to have simply structure for store information. My problem is to create inner method that clear stored values.

```
   public struct GraphValues
   {
        public int min, max, ...;

        public GraphValues(int min, int max, ...)
        {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            ...
        }

        public static void Clear(this GraphValues values)
        {
            values.min.Equals(null);
            values.max.Equals(null);
            ...
        }
    }
```

So write new values in this structure is OK,

```
GraphValues val = new GraphValues()
val.max = 12;
val.min = 1;
```

but I want to set all structure valueas to *null*. Calling something like

```
val.Clear();
```

Any idea?
Thnaks

Comment: I suggest you use mine and Mark's answers together to rewrite this whole thing.

Answer (score 7):

1. Structs should not be mutable. Make your type a class instead.
2. To allow null values, use nullable types.
3. Use properties instead of public fields.

Fixed code:

```
public class GraphValues
{
     public int? Min { get; set; } 
     public int? Max { get; set; }
     // etc...

     public void Clear()
     {
         Min = null;
         Max = null;
         // etc...
     }
}
```

I'd also suggest that you consider if it would be better to create a new object instead of setting the fields on an existing object to null:

```
//val.Clear();           // Don't do this.
val = new GraphValues(); // Just create a new object.
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '`static`' keyword from the `Clear()` method definition, so that it's available for each instance of your `GraphValues` object.  Also, no need to pass in parameters - inside the `Clear()` method you'll have access to all your members.  And you want to **set** them to null, not compare their values to null.

```
    public void Clear()
    {
        this.min = null;
        this.max = null;
        ...
    }
```

And why is this a struct anyway?  Just use class.

Comment: It is available for each instance: he made it an extension method for his class, in his class. It is, at the very least, creative.

Comment: Yeah... creative isn't the word I would've used.  :)

Comment: How can that even compile?  Extension methods must be in a static class.